# Definition of semisimple module over a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm reading the paper "G. Hochschild, J.-P. Serre, Cohomology of Lie algebras. Ann. of Math. (2) 57 (1953) 591–603". I want to understand the statement of the Theorem 10:

Theorem: Let $G$ a reductive Lie algebra of finite dimension over the field $F$ of characteristc $0$. Let $M$ be a finite dimensional semisimple $G-$module, such that $H^{0}(G,M)=0$. Then $H^{n}(G,M)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$.

My questions:

1. What is the definition of simple $G$-module?
2. What is the definition of semisimple $G-$module?

I think, but I'm not sure, that:

1. $M$ is said to be simple if and only if its only $G-$submodules are $0$ and $V$.
2. $M$ is said to be semisimple if and only if $M$ is the direct sum of simple $G-$modules.

Are these the definitions tha I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, these two definitions are correct.

Comment: Hochschild and Serre even say at the beginning of section $5$: $G$ is a semisimple $K$-module, i.e., a sum of simple $K$-modules.